# Assistance with MySQL query for duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, duplicates, sql-order-by

```
Table1
  Colum1
    ID      Name        Size
    1       File23      912831823
    2       File29      823472348
    3       File21      912831823
    4       File24      742834882
```

The basic structure is above, now i'm looking for duplicates on the Size because sometimes the wrong Name is entered.

`SELECT Name, Size, COUNT(Size) AS Counted FROM Column1 GROUP BY Size HAVING (COUNT(Size)>1) ORDER BY Counted DESC`

This gives me the following

```
            Name        Size        Counted
            File23      912831823   2
```

This is progress because it has counted the number of times Size has been duplicated, which is 2. My goal however would be
to get output like this that lists each of the duplicates, but I'm not quite sure how to format that query.

```
            Name        Size        Counted
            File23      912831823   2
            File21      912831823   2
```

I've tried a few different things, even toying with outer joins but its clear I don't know as much as I'd like to about this, who can shove me in the right direction? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do an aggreage count and then re-join to the source table:

```
SELECT t1.Name, Counts.Size, Counts.Counted 
FROM
    (
    SELECT Size, COUNT(ID) as Counted
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY Size
    ) Counts

    LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.Size = Counts.Size
```

Comment: Thanks this is where I was trying to get, I do still want to only list those with duplicates though, so I'm adding the `HAVING (COUNT(Size)>1)` clause back for expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a join to the aggregated query:

```
select t1.*, agg.cnt
from table1 t1 join
     (SELECT Size, count(*) as cnt
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY Size
      HAVING COUNT(Size) > 1
     ) agg
     on t1.size = agg.size
order by agg.cnt desc, size desc;
```

The subquery gets the sizes that are duplicated.  The `join` brings back the original rows.  In most other databases, you could do this using window/analytic functions instead.

Comment: This does list the expected results but it also contains all the fields to the row, and I only need the two which were listed, so it's more data than I want.